# add columns to a query in access 2003 based on unknown rows

Tags: ms-access

I have this query in Access 2003:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 
111  123  001  12.5 
111  123  002  12.5 
111  123  003  12.5
111  123  004  12.5
---------------------
112  211  001  5.2
112  211  002  5.2
112  211  003  5.2
```

What I'm trying to do is to move those rows starting with col3 in columns and suprime the duplicates, I mean I want to have in the end like this:

```
col1 col2 new_col3 new_col4 new_col5......(unknown # of columns)
111  123  001      002      003       004   005.................. 12.5 
 (here I don't want a sum like in the crosstab query).
```

I tried in so many ways, but I didn't get anything. Please, I really need your help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should appear at the intersection of these new columns and the grouped rows? The sum of col4? A count?

Comment: It would help if you showed us exactly what you would expect given your sample inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you want at the intersection of the new columns and the rows. Using what little sample output you gave us, let's assume you want the col3/col4 values themselves. To crosstab multiple columns, you need to use multiple queries.

```
Query1:
TRANSFORM Min(T1.col3) AS MinOfcol3
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2
FROM Table1 AS T1
GROUP BY T1.col1, T1.col2
PIVOT T1.col3;

Query2:
TRANSFORM Min(Table1.col4) AS MinOfcol4
SELECT Table1.col1, Table1.col2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.col1, Table1.col2
PIVOT Table1.col4;

Query3:
SELECT Query1.*, Query2.*
FROM Query1 
    INNER JOIN Query2 
        ON (Query1.col2 = Query2.col2) 
            AND (Query1.col1 = Query2.col1);
```

If the values in col3 and col4 are known, then another way to do it would be:

```
Select col1, col2
    , Min( IIF( col3 = '001', col3, NULL ) ) As col3_001
    , Min( IIF( col3 = '002', col3, NULL ) ) As col3_002
    , Min( IIF( col3 = '003', col3, NULL ) ) As col3_003
    , Min( IIF( col3 = '004', col3, NULL ) ) As col3_004
    , Min( IIF( col4 = 12.5, col4, NULL ) ) As col4_12_5
    , Min( IIF( col4 = 5.2, col4, NULL ) ) As col4_5_2
From Table1
Group By col1, col2
```

Now with all that, we really should ask *why* on Earth you want to do this in the first place. Why not return multiple rows and process the information that way?